# Carousel aren't working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot find my mistake. Can someone help me and explain why my carousel is not working?

Here is the head:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="3" class="active"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/VR/GettyImages-500977426.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/slider1.png">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controllers aren't working when I click on them and aren't sliding to another picture.

Comment: they wont for sure as there is no carousel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import Bootstrap JS CDN

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="3" class="active"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/VR/GettyImages-500977426.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/slider1.png">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg">
              <div class="container">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```